# How to access elements of Cvmat* in opencv

Tags: opencv

How can I print the numbers stored in CVmat* in opencv?
I am facing a problem in accessing elements of cvmat. Please suggest a solution!

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17621084/1601291) might also be helpful for understanding element access.

Answer (score 1):

here with i have given exp code ..its may be helpful for u...

```
CvMat mathdr, *mat = cvGetMat( img1, &mathdr );
    CvSize size_im  = cvGetSize(img1);
    unsigned int M = img1->height;
    unsigned int N = img1->width;
    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for (j =0;j<N;j++)
        {
            CvScalar scal = cvGet2D(mat,i,j);
            printf("pixel val of the image is:%f %f %f\n",scal.val[0],scal.val[1],scal.val[3]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is working , but i am not getting why have u used three scal.val[0],scal.val[1],scal.val[3]); only scal.val[0] is showing output scal.val[1] and scal.val[2] are just giving zeros !Please help

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your comment to aranga,

> i am not getting why have u used three scal.val[0],scal.val[1],scal.val[3]); only scal.val[0] is showing output scal.val[1] and scal.val[2] are just giving zeros

this depends on your image, or more precisely on how many channels it has. A normal image will have 3 channels (RGB, though it is actually in reverse, so BGR), yours seems to be grayscale, or in anycase have only values in the first channel.

And I've just checked, indeed if you perform

```
    cvtColor(src,dst,CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

to convert a three-channel RGB image into grayscale, the grayscale image has only 1 channel. But perhaps you would know why your image is only using 1 channel...