# Accessing elements of mat in openCV

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

Below is my code for to rotate a matrix (declared as rgbMat) by 90 degree, shown in the code below

```
    CvMat* rot = cvCreateMat(2,3,CV_32FC1);
    CvPoint2D32f center = cvPoint2D32f(rgbMat->width/2,rgbMat->height/2); 
    double angle = 90;
    double scale = 5;
    CvMat* rot3= cv2DRotationMatrix( center, angle, scale, rot);
```

## Update

I am trying to access the elements of rot3, so that I know what values I am getting. Like in the following code:-

```
    cv::Mat rot3cpp(rot3);
    for(int i=0;i<rot3cpp.cols;i++)
    {
    for (int j =0;j<rot3cpp.rows;j++)
      {
        CvScalar scal = cvGet2D(rot3,i,j);
        printf("new matrix is %f: \n", rot3cpp.at<float>(i,j));
      }
    }
```

but I am getting error like this :

```
     OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (index is out of range) in cvGet2D, file /home/xyz/Documents/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 1958 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  /home/xyz/Documents/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/array.cpp:1958: error: (-211) index is out of range in function cvGet2D
```

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access elements of Cvmat\* in opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954423/how-to-access-elements-of-cvmat-in-opencv)

Comment: @CharlesB the code given there is not working, can you provide some answer

Comment: For printing the matrix, refer [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat%20-%20the%20basic%20image%20container/mat%20-%20the%20basic%20image%20container.html#print-out-formatting)

Comment: you don't need to use get2d and at<float> same time, they are for the same purpose :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of cvGet2D and cvSet2D?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17612552/purpose-of-cvget2d-and-cvset2d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First loop must iterate matrix rows, because OpenCV uses row-major order. And the first index for `at` or `cvGet2D` is row index, not column. The right code:

```
for(int i=0; i<rot3.rows; i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j<rot3.cols; j++)
   {
       cout << rot3.at<float>(i,j);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all -since you are using Mat structure instead of IplImage- try to use [C++ API](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) for the [matrix operations](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?#getrotationmatrix2d), to get out of pointer / data confusion.

Then,

```
for(int i=0; i<rot3.cols; i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j<rot3.rows; j++)
   {
       cout << rot3.at<float>(i,j); 
   }
}
```

will work.