# Purpose of cvGet2D and cvSet2D?

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

What are `cvSet2D` and `cvGet2D` actually doing in OpenCV? Like in the following code to rotate a matrix, I am using `cvGet2D`:

```
    CvMat* rot3= cv2DRotationMatrix( center, angle, scale, rot);
    cv::Mat rot3cpp(rot3);
    for(int j=0;j<rot3cpp.rows;j++)
    {
    for (int i=0;i<rot3cpp.cols;i++)
      {
        CvScalar scal = cvGet2D(rot3,j,i);

        printf("new matrix is %f: \n", rot3cpp.at<float>(j,i));
      }
    }
```

How will use of `cvSet2D` change my code if I add the line:

```
  cvSet2D(rot3,i,j,scal); // set the (i,j) pixel value
```

before printing the value?
What does "setting (i,j) pixel value" mean?

Comment: cvSet2D: set the pixel(i,j) from image rot3 with the value scal. cvGet is for reading the value.

Comment: @William it's still not clear, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @user2567857 Also, it appears that you're pretty new to OpenCV. I would recommend reading some introductory material for the [C API](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html) or the [C++ API](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html). If possible, prefer the C++ API. It is easier to work with, and the C API is deprecated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short Answer:** [`cvGet2D()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvget2d#CvScalar%20cvGet2D%28const%20CvArr*%20arr,%20int%20idx0,%20int%20idx1%29) and [`cvSet2D()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html?highlight=cvset2d#void%20cvSet2D%28CvArr*%20arr,%20int%20idx0,%20int%20idx1,%20CvScalar%20value%29) are used to get and set elements of a two-dimensional matrix or image, respectively.

**Long Answer:**

Suppose you create a `CvMat m`:

```
CvMat* m = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);
float data[9] = {0, 1, 2, 3,  4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
cvSetData(m, data, m->step);
```

This creates a matrix which looks like this:

```
[0.0 1.0 2.0]
[3.0 4.0 5.0]
[6.0 7.0 8.0]
```

If you want to get the  element containing the value `2.0`, you would use `cvGet2D()` to get the element in the first row and third column:

```
CvScalar scal = cvGet2D(m, 0, 2);    // Rows and columns are zero-indexed
```

But since this is only a single-channel matrix, only the first element of `scal` contains meaningful data.

```
double value = scal.data[0];    // Voila! value == 2.0
```

But now what if you wanted to change the value of that element? Then you would use `cvSet2D()`:

```
CvScalar new_value = cvScalar(9.0);
cvSet2D(m, 0, 2, new_value);
```

Then, the data in `m` looks like this:

```
[0.0 1.0 9.0] <-- note the change
[3.0 4.0 5.0]
[6.0 7.0 8.0]
```